# rpmbuild unexpected dependencies

Tags: rpm, specifications, rpmbuild

I have created rpm from binary files. When I try `rpm -Uvh` *my_package.rpm* there is a dependency problem. Strange thing is that dependencies are not in the `Require` section of the spec file. It looks as if rpmbuild checks my binary file for dependencies (just like ldd). How to prevent this?

Comment: In most cases you shouldn't prevent it. rpm is being helpful and saving you from problems. If the libraries you depend on aren't available then your binary won't work. What specific problems are you having?

Comment: `rpmbuild` automatically adds dependency on libraries the binaries depend on. If required libraries don't exist, simply install them. If libraries exist but version is lower than required and upgrading them isn't an option, compile the source of binaries on a system with similar version of libraries as the target machine.

Comment: my library exist and is part of package

Comment: If the library exists and is part of the package, but is listed as a dependency problem, then that reflects a problem with the spec file.  No spec-file is shown in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short answer; disable the automatic requirements analysis by putting this in the header of your package specification:

```
AutoReq: no
```

complete explanation is here:
http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html

Comment: The provided link is broken. Can you, please, update it? Thank you

Comment: Here is a link that still works:
http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html

However; please note that this solution is not applicable for newer versions of RPM.  It appears that this feature was removed in RPM version 4.9.  A newer feature is available instead; specific parts of the package are excluded from dependency processing.  You can read about dependency filtering in the Fedora packaging guide and the RPM 4.9 release notes;
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:AutoProvidesAndRequiresFiltering
http://rpm.org/wiki/Releases/4.9.0

Comment: Thank you very much, I can (for now) still apply the old solution, but I will keep the newer in mind.